# Wordpress: Having issues with is_home() and is_front_page()

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this snippet in a "portfolio-loop.php" file. I'm using get_template_part to display the loop on the front page and on other pages.

I have this within the loop:

```
<?php if( !is_home() || !is_front_page() ) : ?>
  <p><?php the_time('F Y'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I can't seem to get it to exclude the front page. Could it because it's in it's own template?

Comment: Think about your logic very carefully...

Comment: `if( ! (is_home() || is_front_page()) ) { ... }`

Comment: ooo... but I still can't get it to work with brackets...

Answer (score 1):

you probably mean

```
if( !is_home() && !is_front_page() )
```

Meaning you are not home AND you are not on the front page

Comment: I see... but it still doesn't work. Even when I use brackets (mentioned above)